# Recover sessions from Chrome's Cookies after formatting

Tags: google-chrome

I'm currently helping a friend with his pc(we had to re-install windows), and since he doesn't remember all of his passwords I was thinking that maybe we can extract his Chrome cookies from his backup (Windows.old folder), but I just learned that chrome encrypts them.

Is there any way to extract them? Considering we have the Windows.old folder.

Comment: You should be able to just migrate the Chrome profile to the new installation.

Answer (score 0):

The following application seems to do just that:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html

It will let you view passwords stored in the Chrome userprofile and then export it to various formats including text/html/xml.

Short description from the website:

> ChromePass is a small password recovery tool for Windows that allows you to view the user names and passwords stored by Google Chrome Web browser. For each password entry, the following information is displayed: Origin URL, Action URL, User Name Field, Password Field, User Name, Password, and Created Time. It allows you to get the passwords from your current running system, or from a user profile stored on external drive. 
>   You can select one or more items and then save them into text/html/xml file or copy them to the clipboard.

I've not used the program personally, but a colleague of mine uses it frequently.

I'm not affiliated with NirSoft.